# Solidity Ownable Contract not Working

Tags: solidity, blockchain, openzeppelin

I’m trying to use the `renounceOwnership()` function from the `Ownable.sol` contract and it doesn’t seem to be working.

I’ve got a simple 2-contract set-up, as follows:

1. The first contract is a basic ERC721 Contract - which imports and uses `Ownable.sol`:

   ```
   import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

   contract myERC721Contract is Context, Ownable, ERC165, IERC721, IERC721Metadata, IERC721Enumerable {

     …code…

   }
   ```

2. The second contract imports the first one (“**myERC721Contract**”) and has a function called `cutCord()` which calls the `renounceOwnership()` function that it inherits from **Ownable.sol**:

   ```
   import "./myERC721Contract.sol";

   contract MyERCMarketplace is myERC721Contract {

      … code…



      function cutCord() external {
         renounceOwnership();
      }   

   }
   ```

As a reminder, this **renounceOwnership()** method - which is from the **Ownable** contract - emits an event called `OwnershipTransferred`, declared as follows:

```
  event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);
```

And here’s how the `renounceOwnership()` is declared in `Ownable`:

```
 function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
        _owner = address(0);
    }
```

3. Finally, I set up my front-end JS app to listen for the `OwnershipTransferred` event:

   ```
   let contractOwnerChanged =  myContractInstance.events.OwnershipTransferred({ fromBlock: "latest", toBlock: "pending" })
   .on("data", async function(event) {
       console.log("\n==================\n--->OwnershipTransferred 'data' event = " + event);
       let eventKeys = Object.keys(event);
       let eventValues = Object.values(event);
       console.log("'OwnershipTransferred' eventKeys = " + eventKeys);
       console.log("'OwnershipTransferred' eventValues = " + eventValues);

       let returnValues = event["returnValues"];
       let returnValuesKEYS = Object.keys(returnValues);
       let returnValuesVALUES = Object.values(returnValues);

     })
     .on('changed', async function(event) {
        console.log("OwnershipTransferred 'changed' event = " + event);
     })
     .on('error', async function(event) {
        console.log("--'OwnershipTransferred' - ERROR!" + error);
     });
   ```

I trigger my `cutCord()` function via a simple button-press, as follows:

```
function cutCord() {
    console.log("\n\n=================\n==> in 'cutCord()'!");
  
    var cordCutter = myContractInstance.methods.cutCord().call({ from: activeAccount }, 
      function(error, result) {
        if (!error) {
          console.log("\n\n==>Back in 'cutCord()'!!!  No ERRORS!!!");
          console.log(">'result' is:");
          console.log(result);
        }
        else {
          console.log("ERROR!!! from 'cutCord()' -->\n" + error);
        }
      });
  
    console.log("\n\n=================\n==>EXITING 'cutCord()'!");
  }
```

The end result is that ***nothing*** is happening: on the one hand I don’t get any errors, but on the other hand, the `result` that comes back simply returns this in the console:

[image]

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the `call` functionality, you are not sending a real transaction (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call). A call can't alter contract state and can't emit events.

You have to send a real transaction with `send` (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send). This will give you a transaction hash a result, then you need to wait for the transaction to be mined and you'll see the emitted event.

Comment: WELL. I'm having one of the biggest "DUH" moments of my life right now  (Or at least one of the bigger DUH moments of the WEEK )  Anyway, thanks so much - I appreciate it!